# Emailing with php using sockets

Tags: php, sockets, smtp

I'm writing a SMTP class to send mails using sockets with PHP and almost have success. The problem is that is working randomly and sometimes it takes a lot to send the email.

I noticed that once the "." is sent i should get the response that the email was sent but instead of that I'm getting the server is closing the transmission (the same message when i send the "QUIT" command) and then the message that the email was sent.

So the messages are arriving mixed for some reason...but only with the last two commands: "." and "QUIT".

Anyone can give me a hand?

Uploaded Here: http://pastebin.com/9vweVpe7

PD: I know that i could use phpmailer or swift, but i want to do it by myself to learn.

Comment: i think in PHP, the "barebones" way is to use the `mail()` function, which uses sendmail. I suppose you could write your own socket thing, but that seems to be reinventing a whole lot more wheels than is reasonable

Comment: @sein Hello Sein, I too want to learn on this. Can you please post the resolved SMTP class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several bugs and logic holes in your implementation, but the most important ones that stand out to me as directly relating to your question are:

1. a hole in `compile_message()`.
2. a misuse of `command()` when sending the email data.

Once you have sent the initial `DATA` command and received a response, every line of email data you send afterwards is NOT a command of its own, but you are treating them as if they were. By calling `command()` for each line of email data, you are expecting responses that will never arrive because they do not exist. For each line of email data, call `fwrite()` instead of `command()`. Don't call `command()` until you are ready to send the terminating `.` command (which, BTW, needs to be moved outside of your `if not html` block).

Also, when sending an individual line of email data, it must be prefixed with an extra period if it starts with a period. This is described in [RFC 2821 Section 4.5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#section-4.5.2). Your code is not handling that at all. If you do not escape your email data properly, you might accidentally terminate the email prematurely at times, and subsequent email lines will be interpretted by the server as unknown commands and it will send appropriate error responses. It is not unreasonable for the server to kill the connection if it receives a bunch of unknown commands.

Comment: You're right, as for the dot in new lines i was just sending a line of test, firstly i wanted to have it working before proceed with more data. About the offseted messages the problem was that you need to get a reply just after the socket connection is done, even if you didn't sent any command yet and you'll get the server information and then you can start with the communication.

Comment: Yes, the server does send an initial greeting response before you send the first command. That response not only tells ypu that you are communicating with an SMTP server, but also hints if it supports ESMTP (which offers more comprehensive error codes when thinks go wrong - use `EHLO` to verify) and whether the server is even ready to accept your commands or not.